# How to change the Icons color in the Platte toolbar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, themes

How to change the Icons color  in the Platte toolbar in Android Studio???
[my default color is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ant2i.png)

i love the blue and others but i dont have it.
in the android studio v3.0.1  default colors is blue!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are use Imageview than it have  tint property

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
```